# How to handle multi-type variables in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, vlookup

I have a Powershell script which runs an Excel VLookUp function through a variable that can be of either String or Int32 type. The script runs great when I declare the $Value variable as either a String or Int32, but how can I deal with the fact that the $Value variable could be of either Int32 or String form (Example: $Value = 155 (uint32) or $Value = 90:9123 80:8989 (String)). Any ideas?

```
$files2MX1005 = Get-ChildItem C:\source -Recurse

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" )
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts=$False

foreach($fileMX1005 in $files2MX1005) {

    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open($fileMX1005.FullName) 
    $workbook2 = $Excel.Workbooks.open("C:\Lookup_Table.xlsx")
    $range4 = $workbook2.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:E10")
    $range = $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:FZ1").EntireColumn 
    $range2 = $Workbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A39").EntireRow 
    $range.Delete()
    $range2.Delete()
    $Workbook.SaveAs("C:\StrippedHeader.csv")

    $Values = @(Get-Content C:\StrippedHeader.csv -Raw) -split '\s+' | Where-Object {$_ -like '*:*' -or '0.*'} 

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Values.length; $i++) {
    if ($Values[$i] -lt 1) { [float]$Values[$i] *= 1440 }
    }                

    "UniqueActiveFaults" |Out-File C:\IdealOutput.csv
    $Values | Sort-Object -Unique | Out-File CIdealOutput.csv  

    $Values2 = @(Get-Content C:\IdealOutput.csv) 


    $OutputLookUp2 = @()
    foreach ($Value in $Values2){
        $OutputLookUp2 += "$Value $($Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([int32]$Value,$range4,3,$true))`r`n"          
}
```

Example of what Idealoutput.csv would look like:

0.451564 (INT32)

0.84645 (INT32)

90:4585 90:7878 (STRING)

BA:4545 BA:2525 (STRING)

0.6587 (INT32)

Output of the Lookup would ideally be:

650 (0.451564 * 1440) = X

90:4585 = Y

BA:2525 = Z

etc... for each code.

Today...I get

650

90:4585 = Y

BA:2525 = Z

The Output of the Lookup for 650 is not successful because the lookup does not read it as a string.

Comment: What is the actual problem? You say that the same code runs no matter if `$Value` is a `[string]` or a `[int32]`, so is there a practical reason that you need to differentiate what the type is? Or is this simply academic? Or are you trying to avoid running the VLookup with things that are not a string or int32? Or is the issue that you want to convert strings to integers if possible?

Comment: The problem is when $Value contains both strings and int32. The scrip is unable to process both. It process either the strings or the integers, and gives me an error for the rest because $Value is setup to handle only one type of data.

Comment: @CarlosSousa, you need to show this problem then. PowerShell can expand an array containing strings and numbers within another string just fine. Right now it's unclear what the problem is. Create a code example that manually defines an array you would typically get back from VLookup so that we can test the code ourselves.

Comment: @briantist, please see updates to my original post above. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This condition `$_ -like '*:*' -or '0.*'` always `$true`. How do you want to find something for `650` if excel file contains `0.451564`?

Comment: @PetSerAl , the Excel file contains a value of 650, not of 0.45...

Comment: How `650` saved in `C:\Lookup_Table.xlsx`? As text, as integer, as floating point? Does `VLookup` work on its own? `$Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(650,$range4,3,$true)` does it return what you want from it?

Comment: @PetSerAl , it is saved as General. VLookup works when I do it in Excel, and works when I do it in Powershell BUT...it only works with the 0.XYZ type of data if I set it up this way `$Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup([int32]650,$range4,3,$true)`... and it only works with the AB:CDE string type of data if I set it up like this: `$Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(]650,$range4,3,$true)`...I can't get it to work when the data contains both types of data

Comment: 0.451564 is not an integer.  Do you intend to round to the nearest int32(zero)?  Or convert to float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not convert values not to `[string]`, not to `[int]`, so them preserve their original type. Also you should not export and reimport intermediate results to file, as by that you convert them to `[string]`.

```powershell
$Workbook.SaveAs("C:\StrippedHeader.csv")

$OutputLookUp2 = @(
    -split (Get-Content C:\StrippedHeader.csv -Raw) |
    ForEach-Object {
        switch -Wildcard ($_){
            *:* {$_}
            0.* {[int]([double]$_*1440)}
        }
    } |
    Sort-Object {$_ -is [string]},{$_} -Unique |
    ForEach-Object {
        "$_ $($Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($_,$range4,3,$true))`r`n"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test to see if it will cast as [int32].

```
if ($Value -as [int32] -is [int32])
  {'Value is integer'}

 else { 'Value is string' }
```

then run the appropriate code for that type.

Comment: I see your point and that is an option, but I would prefer not to do that as the code is the same for either string or integer. Is there a more efficient way to do it? Or would testing as you suggest not impact performance of the script?

Comment: I just tested, and it took 0.2 ms to run that test.  I don't think it's going to impact your performance.

Comment: Thanks - now I know this would be an option, for the sake of keeping my script short and organized, I would still like to know if there is a more simple approach to handling this so I will wait for further comments. But thank you!

Comment: Just always cast it then, and don't do the check: `"BlahBlah $([int32]$Value) blah"` or more appropriately `"Blah $([String]$Value) blah"`.

Comment: @briantist, I am sorry I did not get that. I am new to Powershell. Could you explain in just a bit more detail please?